# Angular4 Typescript; Property 'data' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am building an app on Angular 4 using TypeScript. I don't know why I get the error

> `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'any[]'`

for an expression like this. I have taken this out of a component;

```
LoadAllUsers(): void {
    this.AllUsers.Loading = true;
    let AdditionalParams = {
      'page': this.AllUsers.CurrentPage
    };
    this.UserService.All(AdditionalParams)
        .subscribe(
            (users) => {
              this.AllUsers.Users = users.data;
              this.AllUsers.Data = users;
              this.AllUsers.Loading = false;
              this.AllUsers.Loaded = true;
              console.log ("Users response: ", this.AllUsers, this.AllUsers.Users);
            },
            (error)=>  {
              this.AllUsers.Loading = false;
              console.log ("THE ERROR: ", error);
              this.AllUsers.RequestStatus = error.status=0;
              if (typeof error.json == 'function' && error.status!=0) {
                let errorObject = error.json();
                this.AllUsers.RequestError = errorObject;
              } else {
                this.AllUsers.RequestError = "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED";
              }
              this.AllUsers.HasRequestError = true;
            });
  }
```

I can only bypass this error by using; `(users) => this.PrepareUsers(users)`

I must be missing something about TypeScript. What's strange is I can use `error.status`

Comment: The message is explicit. The "All" method return an observable of an array (`Observable<any[]>`). You try to get the data property of the array but it doesn't exist.
You should iterate over the list to get each user's data.

Comment: Yes, I realise that now. I have changed it to look like this; All(AdditionalParams: object): Observable<any> {

Comment: Why are you capitalising everywhere? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Coding-guidelines

Comment: Great tip thanks! Newbie here!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you should change the method signature in your service to something like `All(AdditionalParams: any): Observable<User[]>`, of course, that is if you do have an User model.
Also, variables and methods should start with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The data being returned from your service in the `(users)` parameter is an array. All arrays have the same properties and methods. `.data` is not a property or method of an array.

You can find all the properties and methods on the Array type [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Something that may help you debug your specific problem would be to log the `(users)` to the console and see what the data looks like:

```
LoadAllUsers(): void {
    this.UserService.All(AdditionalParams)
        .subscribe(
            (users) => {
              console.log(users);
            });
  }
```

Your data might not be coming back to you in the form that you're expecting.